# 'From azure' button missing on Power Query ribbon

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, azure, power-query, external-data

I have installed Power Query to access an azure SQL database. However I don't see a 'From azure' button which seems to appear in the screen shots in the tutorials. How can I activate this? Is there something else I need to install?

[image]

I am trying to follow the instructions here:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605

On this page the screen shot at the top does not have the 'From azure' button but the video further down the page does. Is there some magic way to get it to appear?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your Excel window (with the missing button), and also include a link to the tutorial you're trying to follow.

Comment: How do I post a screen shot here?

Comment: Post it on a publically accessible image host (ie: imgur.com) and then edit and include a link to it in your question.  You currently don't have enough rep to post an actual screenshot, but one of the higher-rep users can and will edit it for you to make it an actual in-line picture. :)

Comment: I tried to post another link as well but don't have enough reputation to do so!

Comment: Which version of Power Query are you using?

Comment: Version 2.26.4128.242 - the version I downloaded today

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64-bit version of Office/Power Query? and what edition of Office/Excel (Pro, Standard, Office365, etc.) are you using?

Comment: 32 bit, Office 365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Power Query 2.26.4128.242 release notes:

> The following Office versions are supported:
>
> Microsoft Office 2013:
>
> - *Power Query Premium:*
>
>   - Features Included: **All**.
>   - SKUs supported: **Professional Plus, Office 365 ProPlus or Excel 2013 Standalone**.
> - *Power Query Public:*
>
>   - Features included: **All, except the following connectors:** Corporate Power BI Data Catalog, **Azure-based data sources**, Active
>       Directory, HDFS, SharePoint Lists, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL,
>       Sybase, Teradata, Exchange, Dynamics CRM, SAP BusinessObjects,
>       Salesforce.
>   - SKUs supported: All Desktop SKUs.

So, unless you are running "Office 2013 Professional Plus", "Office 365 ProPlus", or "Excel 2013 Standalone", the PQ installer will install the "Public" version of Power Query, and you will not be able to use the Azure connectors.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful if that was noted on the page I referenced above and on this one: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Connect-to-a-Microsoft-Azure-SQL-Database-Power-Query-9f621fd9-5f22-4c57-b247-eb0be8b7bac4?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE. Both don't mention any restrictions on versions of Excel! I've added a comment about that on both pages.